# Magento modify configurable color dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, magento, magento-1.4

i have a configurable product with some product associated, with attribute Color and Size.
I need to modify Color dropdown, adding the name of the associated simple product, something like this:

```
<select class="required-entry super-attribute-select" id="attribute124" name="super_attribute[124]">
  <option value="">Scegli una Opzione...</option>
<option value="1358">PEARL - NAME OF SIMPLE PRODUCT</option>
<option value="691">U9BMNERO(FLAT BLACK) - NAME OF SIMPLE PRODUCT </option>
</select>
```

How can I do this?

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I can't help you with that fully but hopefully I can point you in the right direction or someone else can give better/more complete input.

I've change the label dropdown once before for adding quantities to it.

`[magento root]/app/code/[local]/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php` (put your definitions in this file)

`[magento root]/js/varien/product.js` (where the select dropdown labels are filled from | copy this file to a new directory e.g. - /js/**[yourcompany]**/product.js)

`[magento root]/app/design/frontend/[package]/[template]/layout/catalog.xml` (points to **product.js** file)

Those are the files & locations that I had change when I was working with the quantities...hope it helps.